# Map ruby hash to logstash configuration file

Tags: ruby, hash

I have the following ruby hash.

```
config = {
  'output' => {
    'elasticsearch' => {
      'hosts' => ['localhost:9200']
    }
  }
}
```

Which I'm trying to represent as a logstash configuration file (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/configuration.html). In this case, something that looks similar to this.

```
output {
  elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
}
```

I've tried using map which is close, but "elasticsearch" should not have "=>" and "elasticsearch" and "hosts" should not be quoted.

```
puts config.map{|k, v| "#{k} #{v}"}.join('&')

output {"elasticsearch"=>{"hosts"=>["localhost:9200"]}}
```

I've also tried converting to json and using gsub, but in this case I need to unindent the string and "output" and "elasticsearch" should not be quoted.

```
puts JSON.pretty_generate(config).gsub(/^[{}]$/, "")
                                 .gsub(": {", " {")
                                 .gsub(": ", " => ")[1..-2]

  "output" {
    "elasticsearch" {
      "hosts" => [
        "localhost:9200"
      ]
    }
  }
```

While each implementation is close, it's still off by a bit. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Logstash config format isn't standard JSON or anything. It may be best to just write a serializer for it. I took a quick stab at it:

```
def serialize_config(config, tabs = 0)
  clauses = []
  config.each do |key, val|
    case val
    when Hash
      clauses << format("%s {\n%s%s}", key, serialize_config(val, tabs + 1), "\t" * tabs)
    else
      clauses << format("%s => %s", key, val.inspect)
    end
  end
  clauses.map {|c| format("%s%s\n", "\t" * tabs, c) }.join
end

config = {
  'output' => {
    'elasticsearch' => {
      'hosts' => ['localhost:9200']
    },
    'ruby' => {
      "code" => "event.cancel if rand <= 0.90"
    }
  }
}

puts serialize_config(config)
```

When gives output:

```
output {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        }
        ruby {
                code => "event.cancel if rand <= 0.90"
        }
}
```

You'd want to check it against more complex Logstash configs, though.